# Same resource request from IE gets HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 304

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, websphere, ibmhttpserver

I have a web application that requests for the same resource multiple times during a transaction. I am seeing that the application is getting a HTTP 200 response from the server where it should be getting a HTTP 304. I have seen the fiddler reports and they do have the `If-Modified-Since` header in the requests. Yet, the server sends the content every single time, instead of just a 304, which is causing quite an overhead. I did not have the problem in my previous deployment.

I am using IBM WebSphere application server with IBM HTTP Server. I have tried changing my IE settings, it doesn't seem to have any that would force such a behavior.

Any tips here?

Comment: Is it a static file served by IHS? Is it a static file served by WAS?  is the WAS Plugin ESI cache enabled? Is it a dynamic URL served by WAS?

Comment: The files are static files served by WAS. IHS is running over WAS. WAS Plugin ESI cache is enabled. It is not a dynamic URL.

Answer (score 0):

What does the Fiddler trace "RAW" format show for Request and Response headers?
There may be other header affecting such as:

```
Cache_Control:
Pragma:
```

or other headers preventing caching or triggering need for re-validation.

Setting the

```
LogLevel="Trace"
```

in the `plugin-cfg.xml` for the WAS Plug-in module on the IHS  webserver is also a good capture of HTTP headers.

Once you find the Process/Thread ID (just after the timestamp) of the request in the Plug-in log (`http_plugin.log` default or as defined in `plugin-cfg.xml`) you can then see the request and response headers sent.

Also knowing your exact versions of IHS, Plug-in and WAS for the working previous deployment as well as the new non-working setup are helpful. Does this occur for newer versions of IE browser or other brands of Browser such as `Firefox` or `Chrome`?  That would help isolate if it is consistent with all browsers or related to type/version of browser used.